# Как я могу установить соедниение с nginx хостом в Docker контейнере из слинкованного php Docker контейнера?

Tags: nginx, dns, docker, virtual-hosts, микросервисы

Добрый день.

Я хочу изолировать инфраструктуру моего нового проекта используя Docker контейнеры и я новичок в Docker. Я застрял с проблемой. Прежде всего я покажу пример моего конфига, а затем опишу проблему.

**Пример конфига**

```
nginx:
          restart: always
          image: nginx:latest
          expose:
              - 80
          ports:
              - 8181:80
    #          - 80:80
          volumes:
              - ../.:/code
              - ./docker/nginx/hosts:/etc/nginx/conf.d/
              - ./docker/nginx/nginx.conf:/etc/nginx/nginx.conf
          links:
              - php
 php:
          restart: always
          build: docker/php5.6-fpm
      #    image: php:5.6-fpm
      #    ports:
      #        - 9000:9000
          volumes:
              - ../.:/code
          links:
                  - redis_loc
                  - postgres_loc
                  - memcached_loc
                  - rabbitmq_loc
```

Это пример. Я опустил детали для *_loc сервисов. Итак, у меня есть 2 локальных домена для разработки, такие как site1.loc и site2.loc. Я использую микросервисную архитектуру, и site2.loc - это микросервис для site1.loc.

У меня есть общий php контейнер для всего кода микросервисов и
у меня есть такой же общий nginx для микросервисов, который сконфигурирован с помощью `*.loc.conf` конфигов. Nginx слушает 80 порт внутри Docker сети.
Хосты доступны через 8181 порт на локальной машине. 
На локальной машине у меня есть фронт Nginx который проксирует 80 на соответствующие 8181 хосты.
Конечно, в /etc/hosts на локальной машине у меня есть записи

```
127.0.0.1 site1.loc
127.0.0.1 site2.loc
```

Таким образом я могу открывать эти loc хосты в браузере и работать с ними независимо.

**Проблема**

Проблема в том, что site2.loc - это микросервис, и он должен быть доступен из php кода в site1.loc.
Сейчас, когда я пробую послать запрос из site1.loc php кода в site2.loc, я получаю такую ошибку

```
'stream_socket_client(): unable to connect to site2.loc:80 (php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known)'
```

Php не может найти путь для подключения.

Я уже пробовал применить docker-compose фишку, такую как `extra_hosts` на nginx и php контейнере, но это мне не помогло.

```
#      extra_hosts:
    #          - "site1.loc:nginx"
    #          - "site2.loc:nginx"
```

Я уже пробовал конфигурировать кастомную сеть, но это не то направление.

Также я уже пробовал `jwilder/nginx-proxy`, но это делает доступными хосты на локальной машине, а не внутри php контейнера.

Я ясно понимаю, что источник проблемы в том, что окружение php контейнера ничего не знает о site2.loc хосте. Предполагаю, что мне нужно что-то вроде hosts мапинга или dns.

Но я не знаю как это сконфигурировать и я не могу найти какой-то пример (гуглил вчера пол дня).

Как я могу сделать site2.loc достумным для site1.loc php кода?

**UPD**

Я только что понял, что можно использовать Consul. Или есть другие пути без Consul?

**UPD**

Помог способ с указанием хостов на 172.17.0.1 в extra_hosts. Подскажите, какой все таки лучше выбрать способ для продакшена - extra_hosts, dns, Consul? При условии, что у меня на сервере будут еще проекты рядом в контейнерах и без.

Comment: запросить по внутреней сети к

Comment: site2.loc тоже внутри своего докер-контейнера?

Comment: site2.loc и site1.loc в одном nginx и у них общий php, как показано в конфиге

Comment: Но ведь nginx и php это разные контейнеры? Тогда, во-первых, откуда php внутри контейнера должен знать, что site2.loc это 127.0.0.1, если запись об этом в файле /etc/hosts локальной машины, а не контейнера? А во-вторых, ваш код внутри php-контейнера обращаясь по адресу 127.0.0.1 будет обращаться сам к себе, а не к контейнеру с nginx. Внутри php-контейнера есть что-то, что слушает 80 порт?

Comment: ilyapt, вы совершенно правы. Именно об этом и мой вопрос. Как сделать site2.loc достумным для php ? Все, что у меня настроено - я показал выше. Мне нечего добавить.

Comment: Использовать ip адрес локальной машины, на который делается маппинг порта nginx. Или сделать php-контейнеру link обратно на nginx контейнер и обращаться по имени линка. Но если хотите использовать именно имя site2.loc, то наверное только первый вариант и прописать соответствие ip адреса имени в /etc/hosts который внутри php-контейнера

Comment: как вариант, можете попробовать использовать адрес 172.17.0.1, тк на него тоже должен производиться маппинг nginx порта

Comment: Если у вас два микросервиса в разных контейнерах, то их стоит разнести. С учетом околонулевых накладных расходов можно завести перед каждым микросервисом дополнительный nginx и линковать их, как угодно.

Comment: "в разных контейнерах" -> "в одном контейнере"

Comment: Etki, у меня была мысль сделать nginx не общий, а на каждый микросервис свой и перед ними всеми nginx-proxy. Но разве после этого site1.php сможет сделать запрос в site2.nginx хост?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда вы в Extra Hosts прокидываете значение nginx, php у вас ничего про него не знает, т.к. контейнеры изолированы, поэтому оно просто записывается в формате nginx site1.loc и все, но связать напрямую линками 2 контейнера, для того чтобы они видели друг-друга нельзя, возникнет ошибка связывания, поэтому раньше применяли патерны аля ambassador pattern.

**Самое простое решение вашей проблемы.**

Выполняем в командной строке:

```
ifconfig docker0
```

Берем из вывода inet addr

```
inet addr:172.17.0.1
```

Обычно он 172.17.0.1, это адрес хост машины в Docker. Далее открываем docker-compose.yml, находим контейнер с PHP и вставляем туда

```
extra_hosts:
   - "site1.loc:172.17.0.1"
   - "site2.loc:172.17.0.1"
```

**172.17.0.1** - адрес вашей машины из ifconfig. Делаем пересоздание контейнеров, `docker-compose up -d`

Есть также решения через создание сети, external dns. Эти решения есть в статье по [Bi-directional Linking Problem](https://abdelrahmanhosny.com/2015/07/01/3-solutions-to-bi-directional-linking-problem-in-docker-compose/)

Comment: Но ведь эти ip адреса динамические и постоянно меняются. Мне надо их как-то зафиксировать, чтобы docker-compose был всегда с правильными адресами. Или 172.17.0.1 всегда такой, как точка входа?

Comment: 172.17.0.1 - постоянный адрес вашей хост-машины. Контейнеры будут обращаться на хост-машину и запрашивать адрес для требуемых адресов.

Comment: Пользователь, который поставил минус и написал, что я неправ, а потом удалил свой коммент, можно было бы и минус тоже убрать :)

Comment: Firepro, помог способ с 172.17.0.1. Подскажите, какой все таки лучше выбрать способ для продакшена - extra_hosts, dns, Consul? При условии, что у меня на сервере будут еще проекты рядом в контейнерах и без.